# How to remove notification icon badge from persistent notification react native android

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, react-native-push-notification

I am using the react-native-push-notification to display the persistent notification. it is also showing the badge on the app icon. The badge is displaying the number of notification. I want to remove that badge, is there some way to do so.

I have tried to manually handle it using third party library but it did not work out, also i have used setShowBadge in channel.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by
setShowBadge = false,
and uninstall your application and then again reinstall the app
the badge icon issue will be fixed